# custom site page does not render as expected

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Im using alfresco 4.2c and during the past few dayz i really tried to crete a site page(such as calender,Disscussions etc.) which is "Knowledge Base" and render that with few dashlets.I followed the alfresco 3.4
(http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fsite-component-add.html)
documentation for create the page site and followed the instructions properly.
But after creating the page site and add it into a site and when i click the particular tab(link which is at navigation bar) it displays only the header section and footer section for particular Knowledge Base site page

the scope='template' does not render :(

All the codings are same as the codes which is mentioned at the above given link .

knowledgebase.get.desc.xml

```
<webscript>
<shortname>Knowledge Base</shortname>
<description>A summary of all Knowledge Base articles</description>
<family>site-dashlet</family>
<url>/components/knowledgebase</url>
</webscript>
```

knowledgebase.get.html.ftl

```
<div class="dashlet knowledgebase">
<div class="title">${msg("header.knowledgebase")}</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="msg">
<#if (error?exists)>
<div>${msg("error.call")}</div>          
<#else>
<table>
<tr>
<td>${msg("label.all")}:</td>
<td>${all}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><ahref="${url.context}/page/site/${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}/documentlibrary
         filter=tag&filterData=draft#" class="theme-color-1">${msg("label.drafts")}</a>:       

</td>
<td>${drafts}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="${url.context}/page/site/${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}/documentlibrary?                    

filter=tag&filterData=pending#" class="theme-color-1">${msg("label.pendingApprovals")}  

 </a>:                                 </td>
 <td>${pendingApprovals}</td>                   
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><a href="${url.context}/page/site/${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}/documentlibrary?

 filter=tag&filterData=current#" class="theme-color-1">${msg("label.current")}</a>:</td>
 <td>${current}</td>
 </td>
 <tr>
 <td><a     

 href="${url.context}/page/site/${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}/documentlibrary?   

 filter=tag&filterData=archived#" class="theme-color-1">${msg("label.archived")}</a>: 

 </td>
 <td>${archived}</td>
 </td>
 </table>
 </#if>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

org.alfresco.knowledgebase.ftl

```
<#include "include/alfresco-template.ftl" />

<@templateHeader/>

<@templateBody>
<div id="hd">
<@region id="header" scope="global" protected=true />
<@region id="title" scope="template" protected=true />
<@region id="navigation" scope="template" protected=true />
</div>
<div id="bd">
<div>
<div id="yui-main">
<div id="divknowledgebaseList">
<@region id="knowledgebase" scope="template" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</@>

<@templateFooter>
<div id="ft">
<@region id="footer" scope="global" protected=true />
</div>
</@>`
```

and i have implemented the
        template.knowledgebase.knowledgebasexml
        template.navigation.knowledgebasexml,
        template.title.knowledgebasexml and 
        template.toolbar.knowledgebasexml 
files as exactly mentioned in the documentation...

but Knowledge Base site page doesnt render as expected and it only output header and the footer.It doesnt output navigation bar, dashlets that i have mentioned within the templates files

please help to overcome this problem.Any support, is really appreciated :)

Comment: Have you created the appropiate xml in the template-instances & pages? i don't see those.

Comment: Nice to hear from u Tahir Malik :) yes i have created those pages and template-instaces as follow, Page:- <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
   <id>knowledgebase</id>
   <page-type>knowledgebase</page-type>
   <title>Knowledge Base</title>
   <title-id>page.knowledgebase.title</title-id>
   <description>Knowledge Base Page</description>
   <description-id>page.knowledgebase.description</description-id>
   <template-instance>knowledgebase</template-instance>
   <authentication>user</authentication>
</page>

Comment: template-instance:- <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<template-instance>
   <template-type>org/alfresco/knowledgebase</template-type>
</template-instance>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks to you Tahir Malik, Your approach is correct.The problem in my approach was i have incorrectly mentioned the `<source-id>` for component templates.`source-id`  should be refers to template instance.

Following is the corrected template.navigation.knowledge.xml for navigation component

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<component>
<scope>template</scope>
<region-id>navigation</region-id>
<source-id>knowledgebase</source-id>
<url>/components/navigation/collaboration-navigation</url>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your template-instance isn't correct. This is a template-instance I've created and it works good:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<template-instance>
   <template-type>com/ciber/create-groups</template-type>
   <description>Create Groups page</description>
   <properties>
      <pageFamily>site-members</pageFamily>
   </properties>
   <components>

      <!-- Title -->
      <component>
         <region-id>title</region-id>
         <url>/components/title/collaboration-title</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Navigation -->
      <component>
         <region-id>navigation</region-id>
         <url>/components/navigation/collaboration-navigation</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Members Bar -->
      <component>
         <region-id>membersbar</region-id>
         <url>/components/invite/members-bar</url>
      </component>

      <!-- Groups List -->
      <component>
         <region-id>create-groups</region-id>
         <url>/components/create-groups</url>
      </component>

   </components>
</template-instance>
```

For your information the template you've defined with the attributes `<@region>` isn't being filled with the appropriate components